# How do Amazon AWS websites determine localization?

Tags: localization

After short trip to Russia all websites insist on showing me Russian versions in Chrome.

IE, I open the following in Chrome Incognito window

- https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/

And I'm redirected to

- https://aws.amazon.com/ru/ec2/spot/pricing/

Any idea how they are determining that I'm in Russia and how to fix this?
Safari is unaffected (MacOS 10.13.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clear your browsing data - **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DELETE</kbd>**

[image]

Comment: hm, Chrome Incognito window doesn't have any cookies